# How can we fix checkmarx vulnerability Cleansing_Canonicalization_and_Comparison_Errors in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, checkmarx, canonicalization

Can anyone help me in fixing **Cleansing_Canonicalization_and_Comparison_Errors** vulnerability in below code-

```
        string appServerPath = string.Empty;
        appPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPath"].ToString();
        try
        {
           FileLoader.FileDownLoad(appPath + DownloadFileCtrl.Value); 
           FileLoader.DeleteFile(appPath + DownloadFileCtrl.Value);  //this particular line is throwing issue
        }
```

Comment: I got this from the interwebs 1. Check for invalid characters in the parameter value by using the `GetInvalidFileNameChars()` method of the Path class.
2. Use the `Combine` method.
3. Perform a last check on the results to make sure the resulting path starts with the base path.  Source https://saiamitparas.blogspot.com/2019/06/cleansing-canonicalization-and.html it may or may not be of any use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.